# can 0-1 knapsack be implemented using 1D array?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I found implementation using 2D array http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/. But how to implement it using 1D array and if it is not possible then why?

Comment: What idea do you have on how a 1D array could be sufficient?

Comment: if you don't care about space-efficiency, then just append all rows into a single, long 1D array. e.g. a[i][j] will be located at b[i*m+j]

Comment: Yes Its possible. check out its answer here :- https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/38836/can-0-1-knapsack-be-implemented-using-1d-array

Answer (score 3):

Note that each of values in the current row uses only elements of the current and previous rows. Hence you can implement the algorithm with an array `K[2][W]`, which is the same as using an array `K[2*W]` with some additional trivial index calculations